# jQuery textarea html style elements

Tags: jquery, html

Greetings I've been trying to change text format within the html element , I want the user to be able to change the selected text to some smaller properies such as bold, italic and underline.

However without success, I have been trying different kinds of plugins but they seem to just replace everything all together and since I do want to keep my code as it is with the option of some slight client sided text customizations.

I don't want more, I don't want less. however I would indeed prefer to be able to use the general html styling properies within the textarea directly, such as 
"Hello my name is b>**Brian**b>

Prefered in jQuery since I do not understand javascript, to solve the solution I must understand it. However worst case, I guess theres more languages to learn.

```
$('.options li').on('click', function() {
  var x = $(this).attr('class');
  var z = $(this).attr('id');
  var me = $('#' + z + '.' +  x);
  var input = $('.' + z + 'box');

  if(me.hasClass('mark') == true) {
  $('.' + z).text('<b>,<i>'+input+'</b>,<i>')//.css({}) don't this, want it to be selected text only.
  }); // MARK
 }); // FUNCTION
```

[My full code](http://codepen.io/Unkn0wn/pen/eBxmLg)

I am open to plugins, I am simply stating that yet I've not found any suitable one. Being one that does not change the textarea and just adds a panel with selective buttons.

Comment: Why don't you use free editor plugins? Your task will be much simplified..

Comment: As I did mention it is because I want to keep everything else as it is. Every plugin ive tried changed to much, I only want thoes text customization options however they provide with more then asked for. Etc, the textarea gets heavily modified without settings to change w/e I've found at least. @RajshekarReddy

Comment: My comment was before you added more details into your post. however even with plugins you have flexibility to enable only required features. However to help you without the plugins I need a clarification. The feature you are looking for is like you can paste a HTML and when you click style it must have all the styles.. right?

Comment: Seems like you are asking to re-invent the wheel when you don't have the javascript background for it. This isn't a code writing service and you seem to be asking to have a WYSIWYG editor created for you. As mentioned, use one of the many different ones available already

Comment: I am not saying im not willing to use plugins, just that at this point there haven't been one Ive tried this fas that has been what Ive wanted, being: Either just the panel without any customizations to the textarea with just a small amount of buttons being the properties I mentioned before. Other case without pluging basically how you would style elements in a HTML document, such as the bold tag, italic tag and if possible underline (the one I don't mind not being usable).

Comment: I don't know afwully alot about jQuery nor javascript, I've simply done this for a week or two. However I did try WYSIWYG without satisfaction due to the reason that it changed the entire textarea without any option to toggle that of and keep the panel. (if there is, that would work greatly as well.) @charlietfl

Comment: *"WYSIWYG"* is a general term  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG

Comment: The more you know, and its only Sunday. Well more specificly it was Froala Editor and a few more, but think that's the only one under that brand name? or whatever it is? @charlietfl

Comment: Did you try CKEditor or tinyMce. They are both highly configurable. Hard to understand why you can't find one for your needs

Comment: I did indeed try CKEditor, however I have not tried TinyMce, but I'm giving it a shot now, thanks for the tip! @charlietfl

Comment: tinyMce did not work as previously planed, however it is the best text editor plugin this far, so it's for sure usable in my project, thanks! @charlietfl

Comment: Either of those would definitely do whatever it is you want. It's simply a matter of digging through the docs and configuring them as you need